# If chained - how to delete?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm doing an application where I have the following scenario:

I have several rules (business classes)

where they all return the client code. They are separate classes that will look for the code trial and error, if find the client code returns it and so on.

How can I use a rule without using a bunch of IFs or threaded IFs in the class that calls the others that contains the specific business rules?

For the specific classes, I used the design pattern strategy.

EX: Main Class

```
public abstract class Geral
{
    public abstract string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {
        var codigo = "";   // logica  
        return codigo;
    }
}

public class derivada1 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {
        var codigo = "";  // logica  
        return codigo;
    }
}

public class derivada2 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {
        var codigo = "";    // logica 2 
        return codigo;
    }
}

public class derivada3 : Geral
{
    public override string retornaCodigo(Arquivo cliente)
    {
       var codigo = "";  // logica 3 
       return codigo ;
    }    
}

public class Negocio
{    
    public string Codigo()
    {
        var arquivo = new Arquivo();
        var derivada1 = new derivada1().retornaCodigo(arquivo);

        var derivada2 = new derivada2().retornaCodigo(arquivo);
        var derivada3 = new derivada3().retornaCodigo(arquivo);

        if (derivada1.Equals(null))
            return derivada1;

        if (derivada2.Equals(null))
            return derivada2;

        if (derivada3.Equals(null))
            return derivada3;

        return "";
    }
}
```

what I wanted and that I did not have to use Ifs in the Business class for validation whether or not I found the code where it can fall under any condition gave example of 3 classes plus I have more than 15 conditions and can increase, case would be many Ifs.

Comment: you are not using strategy in the right sense, your problem looks closer to the chain of responsibility pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's organize all `derivada` into a *collection*, say, array and then *query* the collection with a help of *Linq*

```
public string Codigo() {
  var arquivo = new Arquivo(); 

  Geral[] derivadas = new [] {
    new derivada1(),
    new derivada2(),
    new derivada3(); 
  };

  //TODO: check the the condition: I guessed that you want to return first meanful codigo
  foreach (var codigo in derivadas.Select(geral => geral.retornaCodigo(arquivo)))
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo))
      return codigo; 

  return "";
}
```

If you have a lot of `derivada` you can try using *Reflection* in order to create a collection:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

private static Geral[] s_Derivadas = AppDomain
  .CurrentDomain
  .GetAssemblies()                                       // scan assemblies 
  .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())                     // types within them
  .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)                             // type is not abstract
  .Where(t => typeof(Geral).IsAssignableFrom(t))         // type derived from Geral
  .Where(t => t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null) // has default constructor
  .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Geral)     // create type's instance
  .ToArray();                                            // materialized as array
```

then

```
public string Codigo() {
  var arquivo = new Arquivo(); 

  foreach (var codigo in s_Derivadas.Select(geral => geral.retornaCodigo(arquivo)))
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo))
      return codigo; 

  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of derivada's and then iterate over it

and if any given derivada1 equals None, you simply return it, otherwise you just continue the 'for loop'

I could write up a snippet if this doesn't make sense to you. lmk!

Comment: You should always include a code example in your answer, otherwise this answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple with Linq:

```
public class Negocio
{

    public string Codigo()
    {
        var arquivo = new Arquivo();

        var derivadaList = new List<Geral>() {
            new derivada1(),
            new derivada2(),
            new derivada3(),
        };

        return derivadaList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.retornaCodigo(arquivo) == null)?.retornaCodigo(arquivo) ?? "";
    }
}
```

You can add as many `Geral` derived classes to the `derivadaList` as you want and the code will continue to function as designed.

What is happening here is that `FirstOrDefault` will run the Lamda expression on every element returning the first one that equals `null` (although I'm not sure this is what you want, it matches your example code). Since it returns a `Geral` object, you need to call `retornaCodigo` on it only if it is not null. If it is null, just return an empty string.

Another way to write this would be:

```
public class Negocio
{

    public string Codigo()
    {
        var arquivo = new Arquivo();

        var derivadaList = new List<Geral>() {
            new derivada1(),
            new derivada2(),
            new derivada3(),
        };

        foreach (var derivada in derivadaList)
        {
            var result = derivada.retornaCodigo(arquivo);
            if (result == null)
                return result;
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list of derived classes and call them in Loop

```
public string Codigo()
{
    var arquivo = new Arquivo();
    List<Geral> gerals=new List<Geral>();
    gerals.Add(new derivada1());
    gerals.Add(new  derivada2());
     ........
     ...........
   foreach(Geral g in gerals)
   {
     var val=g.retornaCodigo(arquivo);
     if(val!=null)
        return val;
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is a sample implementation, However you are not using strategy correctly

A better approach will be constructor injection,

```
public string Codigo(Geral implementar)
{
   var val=geral.retornaCodigo(arquivo);
   return "";
}
```

Then instantiate only with the chosen strategy.

Otherwise if you want to chain multiple validations, then use CHain of responsibility pattern.